# Multiple subsets with unique counts and sums in R

Tags: r, plot, subset

I have a coding problem that is beyond my skill level.  I am hoping that someone can help me by pointing me in the direction of the tools that I need to finish this task parsimoniously.

I am trying to create a plot of the number of unique species~cumulative area of imaginary islands.  The first point on my plot will be the the number of species on island 1, the second point would be the cumulative number of species on islands 1 & 2, the third point will be the cumulative number of species on islands 1,2,& 3 etc.

I have 30 islands in total, and my data looks like this:

```
species=c("ted", "ben", "ira", "nic", "meg", "ira", "nic", "ted", "ben", "kim" )
island=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
size=c(10,10,10,20,20,20,20,30,30,30)
dat=data.frame(species, island, size)
```

so far, my best approach would be to do something like this:

```
A=subset(dat, island="1", select=c(name, size)))
B=subset(dat, island%in% c("1", "2"), select=c(name, size))
C=subset(dat, island%in% c("1", "2", "3"), select=c(name, size))
```

And then I could use the length() and unique() functions to count the number of species on each imaginary island (A,B,C, etc.).  I would also need to find out the area of each imaginary cumulative island (in this case A would be size 10, B would be size 30, and C would be size 60).

```
Alength=length(unique(A$species))
Asum=sum(unique(A$size)))
Blength=length(unique(B$species))
Bsum=sum(unique(B$size)))
Clength=length(unique(C$species))
Csum=sum(unique(C$size)))
```

But this would get very tedious for 30 islands, and I want to learn to do it the right way.

So the end product would be a set of new imaginary islands with a number of species and an area.  Something like:

```
imaginaryisland=c("A","B","C")
numberofspecies=c(3,5,6) 
size=c(10, 30, 60)
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, which calculates the cumulative number of species as the maximum, per island, of the cumulative number of non-duplicated species names:

```
data.frame(island=unique(dat$island),
           nspecies=tapply(cumsum(!duplicated(dat$species)), dat$island, max),
           size=unique(dat[, c('island', 'size')]$size))

##   island nspecies area
## 1      1        3   10
## 2      2        5   20
## 3      3        6   30
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried it on my real data set, and it didn't work, but you taught me some new arguments that I can play with.  This approach looks like it could get me the unique values that I need for running cumulative total of species, but not for area.  It is a little bit more tricky for area though because the values aren't unique (ie. there are multiple islands of the same size.  I might be able to do this part as a standalone calculation with the cumsum() command.  Thanks again!

Comment: I used cumsum() to generate a vector representing a running cumulative total of the island area.  

I haven't been able to get the code to work for my data.  In fact, I just tried it on the test data that I generated for this question and it didn't work for that either.  I got an error: Error in tapply(cumsum(!duplicated(dat$species)), dat$island, max) : 
  arguments must have same length

So I am still trying to figure out how to get a running total of the cumulative number of unique species as islands are added.

Comment: I've got the part of this code that I need working, sort of.  The most important calculation that I need to use is the one you wrote above for "nspecies".  I've got it doing a cumsum() on the duplicates in my data, but it doesn't seem to start with the first island in the vector.  The order that the calculation happens in is important.

Comment: @eyerah My suggestion doesn't assume that size is unique across islands. `unique(dat[, c('island', 'size')]$size` take the unique _combinations_ of `island` and `size`. The `size` column of that result should give the islands' sizes. An alternative is to `merge` the data frames. Your error from `cumsum` suggests that `dat$species` is not the same length as `dat$island`, which can't be true for a data frame. This makes me think that your example data don't truly reflect your actual data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I've got it now!